# upload jar file to svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

i have a project in eclipse that i work with SVN.
i need to upload a jar file to "referenced libraries" yet all i managed to do is uploading it to the main directory.

[image]

for some reason the file was uploaded to the main server directory instead of to referenced libraries which there it stayed local. i built the file path correctly i think. in the first place the JAR file was only on the referenced libraries.
how can i fix it?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put the .jar that need to be referenced libraries in a lib directory under the project main directory. This way, when I checkin the project into SVN, the lib directory gets there as well.

Comment: i think i found the problem. when i put the file in my project directory its uploading it to main path. i should as suggested put the file in referenced libraries how ever i don't see this directory in my workspace....

Comment: What directory don't you see?

Comment: That's an internal way for Eclipse to say that the libraries are added as dependencies to your project. It's not a physical directory on a disk.

Comment: when i use build path to add the JAR to referenced libraries. its being added locally that is exactly my problem :(

Answer (score 3):

Try using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). It will show you where you placed the jar and you can make adjustments accordingly.